# Mapping between XML:LANG and LCID in SQL Server full text search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have searched the whole internet and books and cannot find the mapping between xml:lang and lcid in full text search for multilingual content in SQL Server.

Here is a sample, not confirmed in any Microsoft doc:

```
Lcid    xml:lang
1025    ar
1026    bg
1027    ca
1028    zh-TW
1030    da
1031    de
1033    en
1036    fr
```

I found some unofficial sources but I cannot be assured it works:

https://github.com/henrylearn2rock/lcids-xml-lang

https://github.com/Apress/pro-full-text-search-in-sql-server-2008/blob/5916c12181cc23becf26b6c99152b1a62c28f6e2/iFTS_Samples/Sample%20Database/Populate_Tables1.sql

Thanks

Comment: Do the official references not contain what you're looking for? [BCP47](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt) and [MS-LCID: Windows Language Code Identifier (LCID) Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/70feba9f-294e-491e-b6eb-56532684c37f), with the latter mapping the LCIDs to their ISO-639, ISO-3166 and ISO-15924 codes and tags.

Comment: I don't know if xml:lang uses the official LCID or different codes.